# How to store Comma instead of Dot in SQL Server Decimal column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to store Comma(,) in Decimal(12,2) Datatype column at the place of Dot(.) in SQL Server 2014 but unable to achieve this.

I need the following behavior:
When i save decimal value 2.56 in database table then it automatically store this value as 2,56

What setting should i apply in SQL Server so that it will directly convert and save decimal Dot(.) to Comma(,)?

Is there any SQL Server Collation or Locale setting to save Comma in Decimal(12,2) datatype column?

Comment: you can use Replace(Column, '.', ',')

Comment: `DECIMAL` is stored in a **binary** format in SQL Server - it doesn't have neither a dot nor a comma or anything. That is just a **display** concern - depending on your language settings, you'll either get a dot or a comma as decimal separator

Comment: How are you displaying the numbers?

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server stores decimal values in an internal binary structure which does not include a decimal separator character. The separator used for displaying data is controlled entirely by the client application.  Consequently, there is no SQL Server setting to control this.

Although you could convert the decimal value to a string containing the desired separator using T-SQL, the best practice is to do that in the presentation layer where you have more robust functions that can honor the client language and locale.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL syntax uses Dot (.) as the decimal separator. You can't change that.

You are getting 2,56 because of your locale settings. All your queries should always use Dot (.)

Comment: I am not getting 2,56 but i want this behavior so that it store the decimal with comma.
Do you have any idea what locale setting should i apply to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you don't care what SQL stores. What you want is to have comma instead of dot when querying the table.

If so: assume your column `Average` is of datatype `decimal`.

You can do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(Average AS NVARCHAR), '.', ',')
FROM your_table
```